# https, .htaccess and SEO

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, seo

I know there are post here and there explaining each section below independently, but I found it difficult to get all 4 parts work in one .htaccess on the root, and so far all is error 500 or 404.

This should be very useful for those website with SSL and want to avoid duplicated content problem for SEO.

1. all requests http://domain.com should go to http://www.domain.com (SEO)
2. all requests https://domain.com should go to https://www.domain.com (SEO)
3. /checkout and  /customers should go to https:// version of the site only; NOT http:// (Obviously security)
4. https:// request of all other directories (not /checkout, /customer) should be redirected to http:// version of that directory (SEO)

Answer (score 0):

the best code in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

if you use cms wordpress install and active plugin Really Simple SSL .